# Resize Icon FontAwesome5 in React Native

Tags: react-native, icons, font-awesome-5

```
<Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="thumbs-up"/>
```

I want to make the icon to be smaller. what should I do with that code?
I used React Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example below in React Native.
(Cannot give you tailored suggestion with the limited information given.)

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faChevronLeft } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';

...

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} size={18} color={'white'} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the icon component in a View component and give width and height to the View.

Comment: I tried but the result still does not match.. the icon only shows part of the image, like it's cropped

Comment: Post the full code please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Icon` component from `react-native-elements` then there is a prop called `size`.

```
<Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="thumbs-up" size={10}/>
```

Comment: its not assignable, cause I called Icon from native-base

Comment: can you give more detail like Icon component which you are using is from any 3rd party package or you have made your custom Icon component?

Comment: i called Icon from native-base

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer my question, cause I found it

```
<Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="thumbs-up" **style={{fontSize: 20}}**/>
```

so my native base version is v2.15, so all I need was only to add fontSize

so thank you guys for helping me